# @Entitty and @EntityScan not work. I am using spring boot and jpa repository, something occurred many times

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot and jpa repository, but @Entity and @EntityScan didn't work. The logs and main code graph are here

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.detail"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.demo.detail"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

the entity define here

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
public class BizDO extends BaseDO {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String bizKey;
    private String links;
    private String description;
    private Integer status;
    private String creator;
}
```

the repository define here

```
public interface BizRepository extends JpaRepository<BizDO, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bizServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bizRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.demo.detail.sharerule.biz.dataobj.BizDO
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotati

Comment: Do you have any extra JPA-related configuration?

Comment: you forgot to write the package of BizDO, please add it, in case that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote class `BizDO` and jpa-related configuration here

```
# application.properties
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

and the bean.xml here

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.wahid.cse.entity"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```